# Bluetooth Authentication: Always Accept

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, input-devices

When I plug in a PS4 dualshock controller, via USB, a Bluetooth Authentication message pops up in the top right corner with:-

Bluetooth Authentication
Authorisation request for:
Wireless Controller (##:##:##:##:##:##)
Service: Human Interface Device Service (HID)
Always Accept | Accept | Deny

1. according to the panel icon (blueman-applet), Bluetooth isn't On
2. Choosing "always accept" doesn't do anything, the message just pops up repeatedly (until they fill the whole screen)

How do I either 'Always Accept', or stop the messages popping up?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have the same issue, but when I connect to a bluetooth device.

Some weird combination of turning on/off solves it.

You could also try running `bluetoothctl` on your terminal, as it usually prints relevant information regarding bluetooth devices or you could simply turn off the interface from there (given the GUI issues)

You could try this specifically:

`bluetoothctl`

`power off`

`quit`

or if you see some connection issues, perharphs your system is automtically trying to connect to a "paired" device?

You could try manually disconnecting

`list` to find the device address

`disconnect 08:EB:ED:9F:51:79` to disconnect, take the address found above

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using blueman, with i3. I was getting the "request" as a simple notification with no apparent way to proceed. I wanted it to be Always Connect instead and this worked for me.

Similar to Pedro's answer, if you want to Always Connect, you can do this:

```
$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# list
Controller CC:15:31:9D:F4:0D rick [default]
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC SB510
Device FE:DC:BA:98:76:54 Rick’s AirPods Pro
[bluetooth]# trust FE:DC:BA:98:76:54
[CHG] Device FE:DC:BA:98:76:54 Trusted: yes
Changing FE:DC:BA:98:76:54 trust succeeded
[CHG] Device FE:DC:BA:98:76:54 Connected: yes (I'm opening and closing the case now)
[CHG] Device FE:DC:BA:98:76:54 Connected: no
[CHG] Device FE:DC:BA:98:76:54 Connected: yes
[bluetooth]# quit
$
```